# How to correctly position google map on asp.net site?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have created customized map on google map 
[my map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1_A5Oq-V3rEFUlYNoNyGTsyzc6EkEMryt&ll=7.92177723589423%2C80.17320373383791&z=7)

i have embed this to my web site

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3" style="height:100%;">
     <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1_A5Oq-V3rEFUlYNoNyGTsyzc6EkEMryt" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

but map shows , not as expected

[image]

How to fill do that 
any solution?

Comment: Your iframe literally says `width="640" height="480"`

Comment: No. i have checked it by changing the width and height but no luck!

Comment: I see you use the bootstrap class `embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3` it might interfere with the aspect ratio

Comment: @MarcHjorth  , you mean i cant resize , with bootstrap class?

Comment: Try and remove it, then regulate the height on the `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use iframe like this. You'll get the Full window height and responsive.

```css
iframe{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3510.0722724513803!2d153.44808100000003!3d-28.386885000000003!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6b90f10f81718185%3A0x976890f2ee368ce8!2sFIGJAM+IT+Pty+Ltd!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1435707782546" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
  </iframe>
```